# How to make responsive SVG/CSS background with aspect ratio

Tags: css, svg, responsive, aspect-ratio

My header position is `relative` and I have an `absolute` SVG image with inclined edge (One side trapezoid) beside of Logo.
The Logo area should be fixed `450px` and the svg image should be stretch in responsive widths (without changing angles of SVG.)

Here is the concept that Im looking for:
(The gray section is my SVG)

[image: img]

```
<html lang="fa" dir="rtl">
<body>
<header>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 2000 100" height="100">
    <polygon points="0,0 2000,0 1950,100 0,100 z" fill="navy" />
  </svg>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="logo-area">
      <img scr="logo.png" class="logo"/>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>...</li>
        <li>...</li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
</body>
</html>
```

```
header{
  position: relative;
}

header svg{
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

header .logo-area{
  width: 450px;
}

header .logo{
  text-align: right;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px)
.container {
    max-width: 1024px;
}

@media (min-width: 1366px)
.container {
    max-width: 1366px;
}

.container{
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
}

header .container nav{
  text-align: left;
  float: left;
  direction: ltr
}
```

How can I make it with CSS?

Comment: Probably you need to use `preserveAspectRatio="xMaxYMid slice"`.  If this is not helping you please consider editing your question with more details. The code would be nice.

Comment: So, should the SVG scale with the width (except the angle...)? Or is it a "sliding doors" effect where the left or the right part of the SVG disappears?

Comment: @chrwahl Yes it's an static SVG background and I just want to scale looks like grid css. Without any sliding or something like that.

Comment: @enxaneta I updated the image and inserted the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the navy-blue SVG has the width of 5000px. It is positioned 100px right and the overflow of the header is hidden. So, some/most of the SVG is hidden to the left. The logo image is also positioned absolute and to the right.

(the image is also a SVG, but in a `<img>`)

```css
header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

header svg {
  position: absolute;
  right: 100px;
}

header img {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

header nav {
  position: relative;
  color: white;
}

@media (min-width: 1024px) {
  header {
    max-width: 1024px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1366px) {
  header {
    max-width: 1366px;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMzAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KPHBhdHRlcm4gaWQ9InAxIiB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAgMTAiIHdpZHRoPSIxJSIgaGVpZ2h0PSIzJSI+CjxjaXJjbGUgcj0iNSIgY3g9IjUiIGN5PSI1IiBmaWxsPSJuYXZ5Ii8+CjwvcGF0dGVybj4KPHJlY3Qgd2lkdGg9IjMwMCIgaGVpZ2h0PSIxMDAiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjcDEpIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg=="
    alt="logo" width="300" height="100" />
  <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 5000 100" height="100">
    <polygon points="0,0 5000,0 4950,100 0,100 z" fill="navy" />
  </svg>
  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li>Menu</li>
      <li>Menu</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</header>
```

Comment: Thanks it's good. But what about the screens bigger than 2000px ? Can we set the svg width to ultimate? Or does it can to repeat from the left side of svg?

Comment: Want to put contents inside `.container`. I updated the image and inserted the code.

Comment: @FredII I updated my answer to fit your questions and code. Now the SVG is 5000px in width -- it can just be extended as needed. About the `.container`. In my example I don't see the need for it. We have the logo, the SVG and the `<nav>` and then the media query is controlling the width of the `<header>` instead.

Comment: Thanks but I have a problem that I use `rtl` meta in `html` tag. And when I apply`margin: 0 auto` to my `header`, It has white space on the left side (on +1366px screen) and doesn't fill the screen. And when I set the `overflow: visible` it appends y-scroll to screen. Here is my code you can see: https://jsfiddle.net/Gamecock/cdzjx2qp/18/

Comment: As I see it it looks fine. Hopefully you should have equal amount of space to the left and right in any width. If you would like the header to go to the edge you could add `body {margin:0}`. But in any case: You probably have more content on the page - let a parent element or the body control the width of the page and then the header is just a child together with the rest of the content. Use either a flex box or grid layout for controlling the overall layout of the page.